# MICR check printing through Linux (EBS)

Tags: linux, hp, oracle, printing

We are currently working to get a new MICR check printer (Troy Micr - HP Laserjet 600 M601) printing correctly with Oracle EBS. Our EBS installation runs on Oracle Enterprise Linux (Redhat Based). The printer itself is shared via a Windows print server and our windows based application can print without issue.

Within EBS, after finally getting the E-13B font (account and routing numbers at the bottom) to print on the checks, we are now finding the check validation fails. The characters that were printed, although using the correct font, are squished together (lacking correct character spacing).

Within the Linux OS, I have tried multiple printer drivers for this printer, PCL and non, but cannot find any consistency or resolve. With some drivers, the bottom text prints correctly but other fields are showing as black boxes instead of text.

Has anyone successfully printed checks using a Troy Micr printer via Linux? This model printer? From Oracle EBS?